# how to split available data into training and testing (Information security)

Tags: neural-network, classification, dataset, multiclass-classification, training

I was advised to ask my question here.

Recently, I made a post about finding suitable dataset for SIEM (Security Information and Event Management) systems. The goal was to work on classification and correlation to detect security attacks.

I decided to use the dataset from the [Honeynet Project Challenges](http://honeynet.org/). The problem is this: I don't know if I should use the whole dataset set for my project, because if you look, for example, at the [KDD99](http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup99.html) dataset, it is devised into two parts: 10% for training and 90% for testing.

I have seen some researcher use dataset A for training and dataset B for testing, do you have any other ideas? I am really stuck at the part of training vs. testing

If my question is too broad. I don't mind some reading materials that will help me deal with my dataset.

Bests,

Comment: Split your data randomly into train and test, the proportion depends on how much data you have and how hard your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out k-fold cross validation techique. Its a quality control technique which makes sure, the prediction/classification done by a model would generalize well to unseen test data. The idea is to split the dataset into k times and use it recursively to train and cross validate your network which at end can be used on the test data to report the actual accuracy.

Here is a link for reference : 
https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/

Comment: Thank you for answer, I will check this link (I might come back later for more clarification if it's possible :) )